# Magento 2.4.X compat.js:43 Fallback to JQueryUI Compat activated

Tags: magento2.4, jquery-ui

Using Magento 2.4.x seeing the below notice in our browser console.
I saw it from this code. how to fix it? thank you

> Fallback to JQueryUI Compat activated. Your store is missing a
> dependency for a jQueryUI widget. Identifying and addressing the
> dependency will drastically improve the performance of your site.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                        "messages": {
                            "component": "Magento_Theme/js/view/messages"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by certain JS or PHTML files calling jquery/ui as a dependency like this:

```
define([
...
'jquery/ui'
...
```

So to deal with the issue, you need to do a text search for jquery/ui on all files located in app/code and app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/.

You need to figure out which module of jquery/ui is needed in each particular instance you find.